# RequireOnce and IncludePath Website error

Tags: php

Every time I try to access my website (brgy-hab.com), it shows this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once($root/include/template.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\PleskVhosts\ibrgy-   hab.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required  '$root/include/template.php' (include_path='.;.\includes;.\pear') in    G:\PleskVhosts\ibrgy-hab.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 18
```

I think I'm having trouble with my include path. which I am now trying to read but can't seem to understand it clearly.

Comment: Can you include the source code?

Comment: It seems like a concatenation error to me....can you show us your `index.php` code?

Comment: my guess is you are using single quotes `'` instead of double for your include `"`.  so its not parsing `$root`.

Comment: @Hackerman You can view my index.php here. http://shrib.com/panda2016
Sorry i put it there so the formatting will stay the same. all the "//" are my trials. thank you! Also you can see there the `$content = 'view/summary.php';` well its not showing up too.

Comment: @michaelbn here you go sir. sorry im not that good at formatting codes here so i put it in a online notepad http://shrib.com/panda2016

Comment: I have website restriction policy in my work, so, I can't see the file...maybe you can post it as a `gist` on github!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63b212ef28b0fb3a0e0b1fb7f9ed5e59/61650d9cd8d6fb779af48097278df4df4e97425f

Here did i done it right let me know Sir @Hackerman. Thank you very much

Comment: @jin, The code you referred to is full of comment out codes. How can we figure what is responsible for your error?

Comment: @michaelbn thank you sir. Here is my index.php https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0e68fa7b68b3a00b2a28cf60fc020fe3 placed in the root directory of godaddy hosting. you can see it has require_once and content tags. but seems not working and not calling them. please let me know what other file you need to see. thank you!

Comment: Ok, first thing, check the value of `$root`, with `var_dump($root);` ....If the value is ok, then you need to replace this line `require_once($root/include/template.php);` with this one `require_once($root."/include/template.php"); `

Comment: @Hackerman Hi thank you sorry for the late reply. Also i would like to add another info here is my config.php. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/459df57c53cf39de07f6b94212efaf45 ok ill as adviced. thank you!

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory